# Using Lambdas in Maps

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to implement a map with a lambda function in C++11 as such

```
std::map<int, int, [](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; }> test;
```

but that fails with

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for `‘template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> class std::map’`
>
> error:   expected a type, got `‘{}’`
>
> error: invalid type in declaration before `‘;’` token

Any advice?

Comment: You've provided a lambda, i.e. an object; the template parameter must be a _type_, not an instance of a type.

Comment: Refer to [C++ priority_queue with lambda comparator error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807735/c-priority-queue-with-lambda-comparator-error) and [Can the 'type' of a lambda expression be expressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867276/can-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression-be-expressed).

Answer (score 43):

You need to pass the type of the lambda as a template argument, not the lambda itself.  What you want is this:

```
auto mycomp = [](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; };
std::map<int, int, decltype(mycomp)> test(mycomp);
```

Although in fact, since your lambda has no captures, it can actually be stored in a function pointer, so alternatively, you could do this:

```
std::map<int, int, bool(*)(const int&,const int&)>
    test([](const int&a, const int& b) { return a < b; });
```

Though I find the first much more readable.  Although using the function pointer type is more versatile.  i.e. It can accept any function pointer or non-capturing lambda that matches that signature.  But if you change your lambda to be capturing, it will not work.  For a more versatile version, you could use `std::function`, i.e:

```
std::map<int, int, std::function<bool(const int&, const int&)>>
```

That will work with any function, lambda(capturing or not) or function object, as long as the signature matches.

Comment: Note that if 2 maps were declared they would have 2 different types and be incompatible.

Comment: @Jesse: That would be one argument for using a function pointer type instead of decltype on the lambda, like I did in my second example.  But better(for compatibility, not efficiency) would be to use an `std::function`, then it would be compatible even with lambdas that capture and other function objects.

Comment: Note that the `std::function<>` approach will incur more overhead than the function pointer approach due to type-erasure.

Comment: … and the `bool (*)(…)` raw function pointer version may incur indirect function call overhead over the `decltype` version, which is likely to be the fastest.