# std::map with lambda comparator

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, lambda

My below code is giving me compiler error and I an not understanding what wrong I am doing. Can anyone help please?

Basically all I am trying to do is pass a STL map container by reference to a function which would fill it up. This map container also has a comparator lambda associated with it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <functional>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _tagAddressBook
{
  string strFirstName;
  string strLastName;
  long nZipCode;
} AddressBook;

void foo(map<string, AddressBook, function<bool(const string&, const string&)>> &myAddressBook)
{
  AddressBook addressBookInstance;
  addressBookInstance.strFirstName = "Bob";
  addressBookInstance.strLastName = "Parker";
  addressBookInstance.nZipCode = 12345;

  myAddressBook.insert(std::pair<string, AddressBook>(addressBookInstance.strFirstName, addressBookInstance));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  auto myComparator = [] (const string &strLeft, const string &strRight) { return(strLeft.compare(strRight) <= 0 ? true : false); };
  map<string, AddressBook, decltype(myComparator)> myAddressBook(myComparator);

  foo(myAddressBook);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the below compilation error on VS2012

Error   1   error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr>' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr> &' d:\my projects\mapwithlambdacomparator\mapwithlambdacomparator\mapwithlambdacomparator.cpp  32

```
2   IntelliSense: a reference of type "std::map<std::string, AddressBook, std::function<bool (const std::string &, const std::string &)>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, AddressBook>>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "std::map<std::string, AddressBook, lambda []bool (const std::string &strLeft, const std::string &strRight)->bool, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, AddressBook>>>" d:\My Projects\MapWithLambdaComparator\MapWithLambdaComparator\MapWithLambdaComparator.cpp  32
```

Comment: Lambdas aren't related to std::function whatsoever. They're their own class type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Lambdas in Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736997/using-lambdas-in-maps)

Answer (score 2):

Lambda functions are not related to `std::function`. In fact, each is its own class type. If you want to do what it appears you do, you can do it by template through `foo` and let deduction sort it out.

```
template <typename Cmp>
void foo(map<std::string, AddressBook, Cmp> &myAddressBook)
{
    AddressBook addressBookInstance;
    addressBookInstance.strFirstName = "Bob";
    addressBookInstance.strLastName = "Parker";
    addressBookInstance.nZipCode = 12345;

    myAddressBook.insert(std::pair<string, AddressBook>(addressBookInstance.strFirstName, addressBookInstance));
}
```

This works on my toolchain, "Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)". I see no reason it would not work with your toolchain as well.

Comment: I tried but it does not compile on VS2012. Seems like it works on gcc. I tried it on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 1):

Please make an alias:

```
using AdressBookMap = map<string, AddressBook, function<bool(const string&, const string&)>>;
```

Then use it:

```
void foo(AddressBookMap& myAddressBook)
{
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto myComparator = [] (...) { ... };
    AddressBookMap myAddressBook(myComparator);

    foo(myAddressBook);

    return 0;
}
```

As Whoz said, lambdas are not `std::function`; the latter can be implicitly constructed from the former, but they don't have the same type. This means a `std::map` parametrized by one is completely unrelated to a `std::map` parametrized by the other.