# Why can't I pass a function pointer as a template parameter to a map?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, function-pointers

I am currently working on a program, and I want to pass a function pointer to a map for a custom comparator. In the following minimum, verifable, example, however, this produces errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct CustomKey{
    unsigned a;
};

bool compareCustom(const CustomKey &a, const CustomKey &b){
    return a.a < b.a;
}

typedef decltype(compareCustom) CustomComparator;

int main(){
    std::map<CustomKey, unsigned, CustomComparator> customMap(&compareCustom);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the above code with either GCC or Clang produces a plethora of uninformative template errors, entirely centered around the internal implementation of `std::map`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736997/using-lambdas-in-maps) seems to suggest that passing a function pointer type is perfectly valid. What is the issue with my code?

Comment: `typedef decltype(&compareCustom) CustomComparator;`

Comment: @Swordfish Doesn't just giving a function in a place where a function pointer is needed cause the compiler to treat it is a function pointer?

Comment: @john01dav No, function names can decay into a pointer to that function in some cases, but `decltype(functionName)` is not one of those cases.

Comment: @MilesBudnek What are those cases?

Comment: @john01dav It's an implicit conversion.  If you're initializing or assigning to a function pointer, the function name will decay into a pointer to initialize it.  It's very similar to the way arrays decay into a pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing a function pointer is valid, but passing a function is not.

```
typedef decltype(compareCustom) CustomComparator;
```

actually makes `CustomComparator` of type `bool(const CustomKey&, const CustomKey&)`, that's the function itself, not a pointer.

You should use:

```
typedef decltype(compareCustom) *CustomComparator;
```