# C++ vector of priority_queue of strings with custom strings comparator

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, priority-queue

I have a `vector` of `priority_queue`s of `string`s:

```
vector<priority_queue<string>>> queues(VECTOR_CAPACITY);
```

And the question is how can I apply custom `string` comparator to those `priority_queue`s?

Should this be relevant, the comparator I want puts shorter strings before longer ones and when they're equal length uses standard strings comparison.

I tried this way:

```
auto comparator = [] (string s1, string s2) { return s1.length() < s2.length() || s1 < s2; };
vector<priority_queue<string, vector<string>, decltype(comparator)>> queues(VECTOR_CAPACITY);
```

but it doesn't compile with the following error:

> ```
> No matching constructor for initialization of 'value_compare' (aka
> '(lambda at Example.cpp:202:23)')
> ```

---

EDIT:
Comparator that puts shorter strings before longer ones and when they're equal length uses standard lexicographic comparison looks like that:

```
auto comparator = [] (string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
    {
        return s1.length() > s2.length();
    }
    return s1.compare(s2) > 0;
};
```

Comment: A suggested answer for your **how can I apply a custom** `string` **comparator?** question: One idea that I can think of is to make a custom class that has a `string` as it's only member.  With this you could overload the comparator operators to first check the length of the two strings, and if they're equal, then use the `string`'s comparator's themselves to determine which is greater than the other.  This is just a suggestion, there may be better ways of doing this.  I believe that this is what you are asking for, is it not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to pass the instance of your lambda to the `std::priority_queue`, as [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807735/c-priority-queue-with-lambda-comparator-error) says:

```
using my_queue_t = std::priority_queue<
    std::string, std::vector<std::string>, decltype(comparator)>;

std::vector<myqueue_t> queues(VECTOR_SIZE, my_queue_t(comparator));
```

Unfortunately, *copy-list-initialization* i.e. `{comparator}` doesn't work here, because the [2nd constructor overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue) is marked `explicit` for some reason.

---

<sup>I changed `VECTOR_CAPACITY` to `VECTOR_SIZE` because that's what the parameter means.</sup>