# priority_queue with custom comparator as value in map constructor error

Tags: c++, stl

I have created a `priority_queue` with custom comparator which stores string in lexicographically sorted order, and it works as expected.[ Ref. [this]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807735/c-priority-queue-with-lambda-comparator-error) ]

Now, I want it to be value in an `unordered_map`, and I got `error: no matching constructor for initialization ...` and closest thing I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407607/c-vector-of-priority-queue-of-strings-with-custom-strings-comparator). I realize I need to pass the comparator to the constructor as well, but how?

Here is my code as of now :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std; // Used to make code less verbose


int main() {
  auto cmp = [](string s1, string s2){
        return s1.compare(s2) > 0;
      };

  using myQuque = priority_queue<string, vector<string>, decltype(cmp)> ;
  // This code works
  myQuque pq(cmp);
  pq.push("ZZ");
  pq.push("AA");
  pq.push("CC");
  while(!pq.empty()){
    cout << pq.top() << " ";
    pq.pop();
  }

  // This doesn't. How do I pass 'cmp' to constructor?
  unordered_map<string, myQuque> table;
  auto p = table["r"];
  p.push("ZZ");
  p.push("AA");

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cvPfPd

I then realized that I can use multiset as well for this application, but I still would like to know how can I use `priority_queue` with custom comparator in `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a lambda was a bad idea... just provide comparison through the comparison template argument, then no constructor argument is required...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
using namespace std; // Used to make code less verbose

struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(const string& s1, const string& s2) const {
        return s1.compare(s2) > 0;
    }
};

int main() {
  using myQuque = priority_queue<string, vector<string>, Cmp>;
  // This code works
  myQuque pq;
  pq.push("ZZ");
  pq.push("AA");
  pq.push("CC");
  while(!pq.empty()){
    cout << pq.top() << " ";
    pq.pop();
  }

  // This doesn't. How do I pass 'cmp' to constructor?
  unordered_map<string, myQuque> table;
  auto p = table["r"];
  p.push("ZZ");
  p.push("AA");
}
```

Note too I've changed the comparison to take arguments by const reference, avoiding deep copying the text being compared for each comparison (at least whenever longer than any Short-String-Optimisation buffer your `std::string` implementation might have).

Answer (score 1):

Maps use the default constructor when creating new elements.  You could use pointers, but you’d need to allocate each new entry:

```
 unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<myQuque>> table;
 auto p = make_shared<myQueue>(cmp);
 table["r"] = p;
 p->push("ZZ");
 p->push("AA");
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that with custom run-time comparator, default constructor of `myQuque` is not available.

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` must be able to use default constructs for value in case there is no value ready for specyfic key. This is needed since it returns a reference to value which can be used in assignment expression.

To fix it you have to drop `operator[]`, you can use this:

```cpp
  unordered_map<string, myQuque> table;
  auto &p = table.emplace("r", cmp).first->second;
  p.push("ZZ");
  p.push("AA");
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bPnrEe

As an alternative you can provide static comparator to `priority_queue` as Tony Delroys answer. In such case `myQuque` will have default constructor and problem vanishes.