# How to pass custom comparator into priority queue constructor inline within map constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a issue similar to [priority_queue with custom comparator as value in map constructor error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64049187/priority-queue-with-custom-comparator-as-value-in-map-constructor-error).

I would like to have a map whose value is a priority_queue with a custom comparator that requires an outside parameter.

```
void someFunc() {
  int outsideParam = 0;
  auto cmp = [&](int a, int b){
    // logic involving outsideParam
  };

  unordered_map<std::string, priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)>> mapObj;
}
```

The above code won't compile. I understand I need to pass the the lambda into the priority_queue constructor similar to

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

But I don't know how to pass it when the priority_queue is within a map.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the second answer in you link answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64049424/4342498

Comment: @JeJo Try adding an element into the map using `operator[]`.

Comment: As the linked answer says, replacing all use of `operator[]` with `emplace()` and `find()` is the way to go here.

Comment: I can't believe I linked the solution without realizing it. Thanks everybody for pointing it out!