# C++: lambda-expression in unevaluated context

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5808171/3508551) answer to define a priority_queue with a lambda function. However, I am running to: error: lambda-expression in unevaluated context

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<
        int,
        std::vector<int>,
        decltype( [](int a, int b)->bool{
                   return a>b;
        })>
         q;
}
```

Comment: First please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: As for your problem, the simple solution is to just use a variable for the lambda. As shown in the answer you link to. You need that anyway since you need to pass the comparator "function" as an argument to the `std::priority_queue` constructor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I usually don't use it. But I am just practicing STL so it is more convenient if you just wanna play with it. I don't use it in large projects.

Comment: Ohh!  I think I see my problem, I didn't pass the comparator lambda to the constructor! Missed that in the example above!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code is valid C++20 as written but invalid C++11.

- Lambda expressions are not allowed in unevaluated contexts (such as `decltype`) before C++20.
- Closure types are not default constructible before C++20. In C++20 a closure type that has no capture is default constructible.