# what is the type signature of a c++11/1y lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I was wondering if there is a standard way to get the type signature (i.e. the return type and the types) of its parameters of any given lambda?

The reason I ask is that I've always wondered what exactly is the type `auto` in the declaration like `auto l =[](int x,int y)->int{return x+y;}`. In other use cases of `auto`, it's a convenience and shorter alternative for a longer type name. But for lambdas, is there even an alternative way to declare the lambda variable?

My understanding is that a standard lambda is nothing more than a function object, and it is its own type. So, even if two lambdas have the same return type and parameter types, they are still two different, unrelated classes/functors. But this there a way to capture the fact that they are the same in terms of type signature?

I think the type signature I am looking for can be something like a `std::function<>` object of the correct types.

A more useful/involved question is, if it's possible to extract the type signature, this is possible to write a general wrapper function to convert any lambda function to a `std::function` object of the same type signature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [Can the 'type' of a lambda expression be expressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867276/can-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression-be-expressed?rq=1), there is actually a simple way in current c++ (without needing c++1y) to figure out the return_type and parameter types of a lambda. Adapting this, it is not difficult to assemble a `std::function` typed signature type (called `f_type` below) for each lambda.

I. With this abstract type, it is actually possible to have an alternative way to `auto` for expressing the type signature of a lambda, namely `function_traits<..>::f_type` below. Note: the `f_type` is not the real type of a lambda, but rather a summary of a lambda's type signature in functional terms. It is however, probably more useful than the real type of a lambda because *every single lambda is its own type*.

As shown in the code below, just like one can use `vector<int>::iterator_type i = v.begin()`, one can also do `function_traits<lambda>::f_type f = lambda`, which is an alternative to the mysterious `auto`. Of course, this similarity is only formal. The code below involves converting the lambda to a `std::function` with the cost of type erasure on construction of `std::function` object and a small cost for making indirect call through the `std::function` object. But these implementation issues for using `std::function` aside (which I don't believe are fundamental and should stand forever), it is possible, after all, to explicitly express the (abstract) type signature of any given lambda.

II. It is also possible to write a `make_function` wrapper (pretty much like `std::make_pair` and `std::make_tuple`) to automatically convert a lambda `f` ( and other callables like function pointers/functors) to `std::function`, with the same type-deduction capabilities.

Test code is below:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// For generic types that are functors, delegate to its 'operator()'
template <typename T>
struct function_traits
    : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>
{};

// for pointers to member function
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) const> {
    //enum { arity = sizeof...(Args) };
    typedef function<ReturnType (Args...)> f_type;
};

// for pointers to member function
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType(ClassType::*)(Args...) > {
    typedef function<ReturnType (Args...)> f_type;
};

// for function pointers
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<ReturnType (*)(Args...)>  {
  typedef function<ReturnType (Args...)> f_type;
};

template <typename L> 
typename function_traits<L>::f_type make_function(L l){
  return (typename function_traits<L>::f_type)(l);
}

long times10(int i) { return long(i*10); }

struct X {
  double operator () (float f, double d) { return d*f; } 
};

// test code
int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](int i) { return long(i*10); };
    typedef function_traits<decltype(lambda)> traits;
    traits::f_type ff = lambda;

    cout << make_function([](int i) { return long(i*10); })(2) << ", " << make_function(times10)(2) << ", " << ff(2) << endl;
    cout << make_function(X{})(2,3.0) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You are correct the types of C++11 lambdas are anonymous and instance-unique.
the `std::function` type can store references to any kind of lambda I have come across, but there is said to be a performance hit.

Try

```
std::function<int (int, int)> f = [](int x, int y) -> int { 
    return x + y; 
};
```

note the `-> int` can be omitted in non ambiguous scenarios such as this.

C++14 lets us write

```
std::function<int (int, int)> f = [](auto x, auto y) { 
    return x + y; 
};
```

which is handy for long type names.

As noted by @Jonathan Wakely, this approach captures a specific instantiation using std::function with fixed template arguments. In C++14, template variables can be specified. Additionally, also per C++14, lambda parameters can have can have their types inferred via `auto`, allowing for the following:

```
template<class T>
std::function<T (T, T)> g = [](auto x, auto y) -> auto {
    return x + y;
};
```

Currently, VC++, and GCC do not seem to support templates on variable declarations at function level, but allow them on member, namespace, and global declarations. I am unsure whether or not this restriction emanates from the spec.

Note: I do not use clang.

Comment: A `std::function` has a fixed call signature (e.g. `int(int,int)` in your example) whereas a generic lambda's closure type might accept different arguments, e.g. `[](auto... x) { }`), so although you can store it in a `std::function` you are limiting its functionality

Comment: I wasn't taking into account the generic lambdas in the upcoming standard. However, i have used std::function instances to pass closures to other functions. But actually as they are planning to add templatized variable declarations, in the next standard, one should be able to write: `template<class T> std::function< T (T, T) > f = (auto x,auto y) {return x+y;};`

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of using a variable template like that.

Comment: Yeah its a weird new feature. Especially since the auto keyword only when used as the type of an argument, follows the type inference rules of templates, not those of auto variable declarations.

Answer (score 4):

In C++1y there are generic lambdas, and no single call signature (`operator()()` is a template).

Comment: I think you mean C++14. I'm not sure if the new `operator()()` template will mean that lambdas will be structurally equatable. I may be out of date on this though.

Comment: @Aluan: There is no "C++14" until the ratification vote takes place.  C++1y is the draft for what is expected to become C++14.  The final vote could still make some changes.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a standard way to get the type signature (i.e. the return type and the types) of its parameters of any given lambda?

No, there isn't.

> The reason I ask is that I've always wondered what exactly is the type `auto` in the declaration like `auto l =[](int x,int y)->int{return x+y;}`.

It's an unspecified class type, created by the implementation.  The whole point of lambdas is they are "anonymous functions" i.e. you do not know their type.

If you want a known type then write a function object type.

> In other use cases of auto, it's a convenience and shorter alternative for a longer type name. But for lambdas, is there even an alternative way to declare the lambda variable?

No.

If you want to declare the type yourself then don't use a lambda expression.

> My understanding is that a standard lambda is nothing more than a function object, and it is its own type. So, even if two lambdas have the same return type and parameter types, they are still two different, unrelated classes/functors.

Correct. Each lamda expression generates a unique type.

> But this there a way to capture the fact that they are the same in terms of type signature?

No, there is no language feature to allow that.

> I think the type signature I am looking for can be something like a std::function<> object of the correct types.

Even if it was possible in C++11, it would not help in C++14 where lambda expressions can take any number and any type of argument, e.g. `[](auto... a) { }`

And anyway, if you don't know the call signature of your lambda function then I would say you are using lambdas wrong. When you write the lambda you should know what its properties are, so either use it right away or put it in a `std::function` (or some other type that captures its call signature) as early as possible, when you know its properties.  If you're creating lambdas and using them non-locally where you don't know the call signature, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: "No, there is no language feature to allow that." which is equivalent to say that, at least the polymorphic lambdas from C++1y, can't be templated, I'm not sure this is correct, I think I have seen templated lambdas before in relation to new C++1y features for polymorphic lambdas.

Comment: "No, there is no language feature to allow that"
But in the example from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type
we see the type of lambda function coded as  a name when incapsulated in the std::function.
Assuming such a name being unique, it seems to be a way to see if 2 types are the same. Is it right ?

Comment: @ZviDan, no. Because I can do `std::function<void(int)> f( [](long) { return true; } );` where the actual call signature of the lambda is `bool(long)` but I'm stored it in a `function<void(int)>`. I could also do `function<void(int)> f2( [](auto...) { return 11; } )` which stores a completely different lambda in the same type of `std::function`. OP wants to find out the *actual* call signature of the lambda, not the call signature of a `std::function` which might be able to store the lambda, but isn't necessarily the same.

Comment: @ZviDan and also, to store it in a `std::function` with a similar call signature, you have to already know _a priori_ what the lambda's call signature is (or at least, that it's compatible with the `std::function` type). But if you already know it, then you don't need to find it out (which is what the OP was asking for).

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK, but can you explain the sense of the fact, if 2 (different) lambdas has the same type name in the sense of example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/target_type ?
What does such equivalence (if it happens) mean, in what sense 2 lambdas are similar in this case ?

Comment: They don't have the same type name, that's not what the example is showing.