# How to infer a function type parameter in a template function with a lambda passed as argument?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, type-inference

Consider the following:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename>
class C;

template<typename R, typename T>
class C<R(&)(T)> {
public:
    template<typename F>
    C(F&& fun) {}
};

template<typename T>
C<T> makeC(T&& fun) {
    return C<T>(std::forward<T>(fun));
}

int foo(int a){return a;}

int main() {
    auto p1 = makeC(foo); // OK
    auto p2 = C<int(&)(int)>([](int a){return a;});   // OK
    // auto p3 = makeC([](int a){return a;}); // FAIL
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63f46d7e92870e82)

The declaration of `p3` fails because the compiler can't infer the type `int(&)(int)` from the lambda that was passed as parameter. `p1` is ok because the type can be easily infered from the function `foo`, and `p2` is ok because the type is explicitly declared.

It fails with:

`error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class C<main()::<lambda(int)> >'`

Is there any way to make the compiler infer the function type corretly, given a lambda?

> P.S.: C++17 answers are also ok, if applicable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657627/what-is-the-type-signature-of-a-c11-1y-lambda-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that a lambda function has it own type, that cannot be reduced to `R(&)(T)`. Because of that, `C<T>` is an incomplete type as correctly outlined by the compiler.

---

As long as you use non-capturing lambdas, you can rely on the fact that they decay to function pointers and do this:

```
auto p3 = makeC(*(+[](int a){return a;}));
```

Or this:

```
template<typename T>
auto makeC(T&& fun) -> C<decltype(*(+std::forward<T>(fun)))> {
    return C<decltype(*(+std::forward<T>(fun)))>(std::forward<T>(fun));
}
```

Another possible solution that works with capturing lambdas is this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class C: T {
    template<typename F>
    C(F&& fun): T{std::forward<F>(fun)} {}
};

template<typename R, typename T>
class C<R(&)(T)> {
public:
    template<typename F>
    C(F&& fun) {}
};

template<typename T>
C<T> makeC(T&& fun) {
    return C<T>(std::forward<T>(fun));
}

int foo(int a){return a;}

int main() {
    auto p1 = makeC(foo);
    auto p2 = C<int(&)(int)>([](int a){return a;});
    auto p3 = makeC([](int a){return a;});
}
```

This way, when dealing with a lambda, `C` actually inherits from it and privately *contains* its `operator()`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Your final solution works great, but unfortunately I need to be able to distinguigh the lambda's parameter type(s) in my template instance. I guess I'll stick to only supporting non-capturing lambdas, as it's not a terrible limitation in my scenario.