# check if two function signatures are of same type

Tags: c++

How to check if two function signatures are of same type. This is what I tried but not compiling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct Employee {
    int id;
    int age;

    Employee(const int id, const int age) {
        this->id = id;
        this->age = age;
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << "ID: " << id << ", AGE: " << age << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Comp>
const T& get_min_emp(const T& a, const T& b, Comp comp) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Comp, bool(*)(const T&, const T&)>::value, "invalid comparator");
    return comp(a, b) ? a : b;
}

int main() {
    Employee employee1(23, 674);
    Employee employee2(234789, 1398);

    const auto& emp = get_min_emp(employee1, employee2, [] (const Employee& emp1, const Employee& emp2) -> bool {
        return emp1.id < emp2.id;
    });
    emp.print();
}
```

Error

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'const T& get_min_emp(const T&, const T&, Comp) [with T = Employee; Comp = main()::<lambda(const Employee&, const Employee&)>]':
<source>:29:34:   required from here
<source>:21:68: error: static assertion failed: invalid comparator
   21 |     static_assert(std::is_same<Comp, bool(*)(const T&, const T&)>::value, "invalid comparator");
      |                                                                    ^~~~~
<source>:21:68: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
```

Comment: FYI your constructor should be written as `Employee(const int id, const int age) : id(id), age(age) {}`, i.e. using member-wise construction instead of assignment in the body.

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question. Also `Comp` is the type of the lambda object, it does not have a function signature.

Comment: "not compiling" ? How?  When there are compiler errors, please include them in the question. It would also help if you explain what the aim of that static assert is. Why do you want to require `COmp` to have exactly that signature? Note that standard algorithms are much more generous, they allow conversions

Comment: if you do the same as standard algorithm you would merely require that `return comp(a, b) ? a : b;` is valid, but not much more

Comment: **A lambda is not a function. It does not have a function signature.**

Comment: [What is the type signature of a c++11/1y lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657627/what-is-the-type-signature-of-a-c11-1y-lambda-function)

Comment: from C++17 you can use : 

`static_assert(std::is_invocable_r<bool, Comp, const T&, const T&>::value, "invalid comparator");`

Comment: Or change the function signature to `template<typename T>
const T& get_min_emp(const T& a, const T& b, std::function<bool(const T&, const T&)> comp)`

Answer (score 5):

With C++17 you could use [std::is_invocable_r](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) as shown below

```
template<typename T, typename Comp>
const T& get_min_emp(const T& a, const T& b, Comp comp) {
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, Comp, const T&, const T&>,
                  "invalid comparator");
    return comp(a, b) ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> check if two function signatures are of same type

The problem is that **you're not actually passing two "function"s** to `std::is_same`. Instead one of your arguments is a lambda which is not a function and so do not have a function signature. Thus you cannot compare it like in `std::is_same<Comp, bool(*)(const T&, const T&)>::value`.

A lambda is an object of some compiler specific class-type with overloaded `operator()`.

From [expr.prim.lambda]:

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non union **class type** — called the closure type

---

With C++17 you can use `std::invocable_r`:

```
static_assert(std::is_invocable_r<bool, Comp, const T&, const T&>::value, "invalid comparator");
```

Comment: If I want the comparator signature should be of some type, how do I do that?

Comment: How does standard library achieve this. For eg if the comparator function needs to return `bool` type and if I pass a lambda function that returns `float` which is incorrect

Comment: *How does standard library achieve this* The standard library generally does not require certain signatures for comparators, but only that the result is convertible to `bool`. Therefore, a comparator that returns `float` can be used because `float` is convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @Harry the formulation is rather convoluted, but you can read an example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort. It boils down to what I said above, anything that makes `return comp(a, b) ? a : b;` is "ok". Arguments of `comp` are different type? No issue when there is a conversion. Return type is `int` ? No issue, as there is conversion to `bool`