# Deduce function type of overloaded function based on argument types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading, overload-resolution

Suppose there is an overloaded function:

```
void overloaded(int) {}
void overloaded(void) {}
```

Because I don't want to (or can) write down the full function signature (like `void(int)` or `void(void)`) I need to get this signature using only the function name (`overloaded`) and
its argument type(s) (`int` or `void`).

I tried several approaches using `decltype` and friends, but unfortunately to no success.

So, in short, I need something like this:

```
cout << typeid(
  get_overload(overloaded,(int)0))::type /* where the magic happens */
  .name() << endl;
```

Comment: Really the only difference between this and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738775/c11-how-to-write-a-wrapper-function-to-make-stdfunction-objects/21740143#21740143 is that the other wants to deduce and then store in a `std::function`, so the answers there (mostly) apply to this answer

Comment: But like the other answer, I'm not sure _why_ you think you need this.  Why can't you write the full function signature?

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use the name `overloaded` inside the type function, this will do:

```
template<typename... A>
using sig = decltype(overloaded(std::declval<A>()...))(A...);
```

`sig<int>` gives `void(int)`, and `sig<>` gives `void()`.

This is just a wrapper of tclamb's solution in a template alias.

Comment: Notice that this will work even in non-exact matches (I don't know whether this is intended - the OP said "argument types", but then gave the parameter types...). For example, if `A` is `<long>`, your call still succeeds but `sig<long>` is `void(long)` which is not the exact type.

Comment: Right I guess this is what your answer does.