# C++: Generic "call-functions-f-followed-by-g" method?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it possible to have a generic method which takes in two functions `f` and `g` (both returning `void` and taking in arguments of the same type) and return a new function which takes in arguments of the same type as `f` and `g` and first applies `f` to the passed arguments and then `g`?

Specifically, I want to define something like this:

```
template <typename FunctionType>
// FunctionType is void(ArgType1 arg1, ArgType2 arg2, ..)
FunctionType CombineTwoFunctions(FunctionType f, FunctionType g) {
  // Using the lambda syntax just for illustration:
  return [f, g](ArgsOf(FunctionType) args) {
     f(args);
     g(args);
  };
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer and then realized I misread it. Are the functions known at compile time?

Comment: Use a generic lambda if you have C++14 access: `return [&](auto&&... xs)`

Comment: Something like [this?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35a90c6ccdeca051)

Comment: @Alejandro Be careful, you're expanding `args...` inside the template parameters and argument list of `std::forward` when that function only takes a single template and function argument. It should be `f(forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)`

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oooh.. good point. My bad! Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most optimised code, but it works.

With help of `make_function` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21740143/642626)

```
template <typename ...Args>
std::function<void(Args...)> CombineTwoFunctionsHelper(std::function<void(Args...)> f, std::function<void(Args...)> g) {

  return [f, g](Args ...args) {
     f(args...);
     g(args...);
  };
}

template <typename F1, typename F2>
auto CombineTwoFunctions(F1 f1, F2 f2) -> decltype(make_function(f1)) {
  return CombineTwoFunctionsHelper(make_function(f1), make_function(f2));
}

void print1(int i, std::string s) {
    std::cout << "print1 " << i << s << std::endl;   
}

void print2(int i, std::string s) {
    std::cout << "print2 " << i << s << std::endl;   
}

int main() {
    auto fg = CombineTwoFunctions(print1, print2);
    fg(1, "test");
}
```

[Full code at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f35ec836538cde)

You should be able to improve it by adding (universal) references to argument and forward them to avoid copies. But note that you *cannot* move an argument twice.

---

As @0x499602D2 said in the comment, C++14 make it much eaiser

```
template <typename F1, typename F2>
auto CombineTwoFunctions(F1 f, F2 g) {
  return [f, g](auto&& ...args) {
     f(args...);
     g(args...);
  };
}

void print1(int i, std::string s) {
    std::cout << "print1 " << i << s << std::endl;   
}

void print2(int i, std::string s) {
    std::cout << "print2 " << i << s << std::endl;   
}

int main() {
    auto fg = CombineTwoFunctions(print1, print2);
    fg(1, "test");
}
```

[Full code at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a33b2a3831bde8cc)