# Generate new type whenever function called in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to generate new type whenever a function is called?
I've read that each lambda has its own unique type, so I've tried:

```
template<class T, class F> struct Tag { };
template<class T>
auto func(const T &t) -> auto
{
    auto f = [] () {};
    return Tag<T, decltype(f)>();
}
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(func(0)), decltype(func(1))>, "type should be different.");
```

But, static_assert fails.

Can I make `func()` return a value of different type whenever func() called regardless of type `T` and the value of `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not when the function is called. Types are generated at compile time, not at runtime.

Have a look at the question [Can the 'type' of a lambda expression be expressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867276/can-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression-be-expressed?rq=1) Here is a code based on an answer from there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  auto n = [](int l, int r) { return l > r; };
  auto m = [](int l, int r) { return l > r; };
  std::set<int, decltype(n)> s(n);
  std::set<int, decltype(m)> ss(m);
  std::set<int, decltype(m)> sss(m);

  std::cout << (std::is_same<decltype(s), decltype(ss)>::value ? "same" : "different") << '\n';
  std::cout << (std::is_same<decltype(ss), decltype(sss)>::value ? "same" : "different") << '\n';

}
```

Result:

```
different
same
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a *statically typed* language, which means the types only exist in the source code, and there is little trace of them left in the runtime. 
Lambdas are no exception - they do have unique types, but those are defined at the compile time.

Templates can indeed be used to generate new types, and that is possible because templates are evaluated at compile time and therefore only exist in the source code as well.
 So the strict answer is no, you cannot generate new types when the function is called, as function calls happen in runtime.

This being said, you can achieve pretty much any desirable flexibility in C++ with some clever design, just check out some common design patterns.