# Is it safe to assume that identical lambda expressions have different types?

Tags: c++, optimization, lambda, language-lawyer

I am experimenting with lambdas and the fact that different lambda expressions have different types, even though they are the same. Consider this code

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void once(T t){
    static bool first_call = true;
    if (first_call) t();
    first_call = false;
}

int main() {    
    int counter = 0;
    auto a = [&counter](){counter++;};
    once(a);
    once(a);
    std::cout << counter;              // 1

    auto b = a;                        // same type
    once(b);
    std::cout << counter;              // 1

    auto c = [&counter](){counter++;}; // different type
    once(c);
    once(c);               
    std::cout << counter;              // 2
}
```

This prints `112`, ie `a` and `b` are of course of same type and `c` has a different type.

**Is the compiler allowed to let `c` be of the same type than `a`?**

I mean the expressions are identical and it would be an obvious optimization.

PS: In case the capture prevents such an optimization, then what about lambdas without capture?

related: [what is the type signature of a c++11/1y lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657627/what-is-the-type-signature-of-a-c11-1y-lambda-function) and [Can the 'type' of a lambda expression be expressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867276/can-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression-be-expressed?rq=1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Is the compiler allowed to let `c` be of the same type than `a`?**

No. `[&counter](){counter++;}` is a lambda expression and per [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-1.sentence-1):

> The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.

So, for each lambda expression, even if it is identical to a previous one, you will get a unique type.

You can use `typeid` to check that this is the case like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T> void once(T t){
    static bool first_call = true;
    std::cout << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
    if (first_call) {
        t();
    }
    first_call = false;
}

int main() {    
    int counter = 0;
    auto a = [&counter](){counter++;};
    once(a);
    once(a);
    std::cout << counter << std::endl; // 1

    auto b = a;                        // same type
    once(b);
    std::cout << counter << std::endl; // 1

    auto c = [&counter](){counter++;}; // different type
    once(c);
    once(c);               
    std::cout << counter << std::endl; // 2
}
```

result:

```
Z4mainEUlvE_                                                                                                          
Z4mainEUlvE_                                                                                                          
1                                                                                                                     
Z4mainEUlvE_                                                                                                          
1                                                                                                                     
Z4mainEUlvE0_                                                                                                         
Z4mainEUlvE0_                                                                                                         
2
```

and you can see there are two function template instantiations.

Comment: i have to admit my standardese is really crappy. Is it maybe the case that in general each expression is considered to be unique even if it says the same thing?

Comment: @user463035818 Well `a += 10;` will always have the same type no matter where you call it.  lambdas are a special type of expression as they are just syntactic sugar for writing a functor. So, I wouldn't say every expression is unique, but you are guaranteed that the type of every lambda expression is unique.

Comment: @user463035818 Note that this rule is the reason why you cannot pass any lambda to a non-template function: You cannot write down its type to declare the argument. This inability to pass around lambdas, in turn, is the reason why `std::function<>` exists: It type-erases the unique lambda type, and provides you with a type based on the lambda's signature which you can actually write down.

Comment: yes `a += 10;` always has the same type, i was refering to `a += 10; a += 10;` being two distinct (unique) expressions. I never considered this before. If in my code the two appearences of `[&counter](){counter++;};` would be considered to be one and the same expression, then the part you quoted would allow them to have the same type, but they dont